# Setting up gsm modem and cakephp app to send sms in windows

Tags: php, cakephp, sms, gsm

my boss at work told me we need sms confirmation functionality. He tolde me to do this using GSM Modem. I have been on stack overflow on several days gor searching an answer what script to use to send sms, but none of them work to me.

I have tried PHP serial extension, [Remy Sanchez PHP serial class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3679-PHP-Communicate-with-a-serial-port.html) with its modifications so far. None of them work. Can you suggest me something better?

Im ar running my local apache server on Xampp with PHP 5.4.27 and CakePHP 2.4.2.

Comment: If your stuck with this sort of task. Id suggest tell your manager, as setting up a messaging server can be tricky. You could suggest an already established API to twilio (Google them). They're a sms service and have established APIs through Google. They do not require a monthly subscription, you just put money into the twilio account and use it up, it'll be time and somewhat cost effective

Comment: I already suggested using API, but they still want gsm modem to work :D

Comment: I am thinking of using some script written in different language and call it in my code using system() functuin

Comment: Then I cannot suggest further, I think setting up a GSM modem might be better suited for serverfault

Comment: I succeeded when trying Clickatell, but my boss still wants gms functionality implemented :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know you did mention on using GSM modem but IMO using a webservice could be a better idea. You might need to explain the pros and cons to your boss. One service I find very easy to use is Twilio https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms .

Comment: I looked into Twillio, but apparently I can't send sms to foreign countries from my country (Lithuania) using Twillio

Comment: @kaktusas2598 well that was something I didn't realise. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What about using Clickatell?